# How to make time_ago_in_words display seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like `time_ago_in_words()` to display seconds

For example, if the event happened 20 seconds ago, I would like it to say "About 20 seconds ago", or something to that effect

Is this possible?

I have tried

```rb
<%= time_ago_in_words(@value, options = {seconds: true} ) %>
```

and

```rb
<%= time_ago_in_words(@value, seconds: true ) %>
```

But neither works

Also, I cannot see anything [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words)

Comment: The documentation link you posted says `include_seconds` is the name of the option. Did you try that?

Comment: @spike Thanks spike I missed it somehow. `include_seconds: true` works

Comment: Great, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is called `include_seconds`, as seen in the documentation at https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words. Use it like this:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@value, include_seconds: true ) %>
```